# Android Drag and Drop and visibility of component

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, visibility

I have a Button in a fragment that the visibility property of the button is set to "GONE". And i want to set the visibility  to "VISIBLE" when Drag and Drop operation starts. and also set the visibility to gone when drag and drop operation ends, How can i do this ?

**Edit:** i used the View.OnDragListener but when the visibility is set to "GONE" or "INVISIBLE" it will not call the View.OnDraglistener at all.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I faced this issue as well. Had a few images, which could be reordered, and also an area, on which when the image was dropped, it was deleted. All images had a specific drop listener, and the deletion area had a different drop listener (because of its purpose). Everything worked fine, and used all the standard API, but I wanted the drop area to appear only when the drag started and to disappear when the drag ends (or the item was dropped on it for deletion). And here this "bug" (I guess) appeared: if the visibility of the view is changed (initially its invisible, then make it visible when needed, then invisible again). It appears that **if the visibility of the view is altered**, the listener is canceled/missing/not working, and setting/resetting it doesn't change anything.

The solution for me was to set its transparency (alpha)

```
view.setAlpha(0); //transparent thus invisible
view.setAlhpa(1f); //opaque, visible
```

Wanted to share this in case someone will face this as well.

By the way, use INVISIBLE if you want to hide a view, GONE has different consequences http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: i wanted to do the same, and the solution for me was changing width  of my component. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use onDrag Listener, here is the Android documentation on it

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnDragListener.html

and here is a good example:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html

Comment: I used befor i ask the question but when the visibility is set to "GONE" or "INVISIBLE" it will not call the View.OnDraglistener at all :(